# Selecting XML nodes with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

My XMLData is stored under table.[column] : dbo.promotions.[PromotionDiscountData]
and the XML looks like the following when i expand it:

```
<ArrayOfPromotionDiscountBase xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <PromotionDiscountBase xsi:type="OrderPromotionDiscount">
    <DiscountType>Fixed</DiscountType>
    <DiscountAmount>5.0000</DiscountAmount>
  </PromotionDiscountBase>
</ArrayOfPromotionDiscountBase>
```

I would like to export a report and flatten out the xml as a column with everything else in the dbo.promotions table.
What would be the best way to get the DiscountType and DiscountAmount Out of the xml?

Thanks!

Comment: Using XQUERY. What have you tried so far and why didn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,[xmlData] XML NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO @tbl([xmlData])
VALUES 
(N'<ArrayOfPromotionDiscountBase xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <PromotionDiscountBase xsi:type="OrderPromotionDiscount">
    <DiscountType>Fixed</DiscountType>
    <DiscountAmount>5.0000</DiscountAmount>
  </PromotionDiscountBase>
</ArrayOfPromotionDiscountBase>');
-- DDL and data population, end

SELECT ID
    , col.value('(DiscountType)[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS [DiscountType]
    , col.value('(DiscountAmount)[1]', 'DECIMAL(10,4)') AS [DiscountAmount]
FROM @tbl AS tbl
      CROSS APPLY tbl.[xmlData].nodes('/ArrayOfPromotionDiscountBase/PromotionDiscountBase') AS tab(col);
```

Comment: I recommend the `text` property when querying XML in SQL Server with `value`; I can't remember the exact reason, but it does have a performance benefit.

Comment: Thanks! with this xquery, i found exactly what i have done wrong with my previous try! thanks for the great help!!

Comment: If the XML does not include repeating elements it is better in performance to use `(/ArrayOfPromotionDiscountBase/PromotionDiscountBase/DiscountType/text())[1]` and repeat this for all needed elements. Although it is better to read like this... `.nodes()` will have to create a derived set, which is not really needed here and which is a rather heavy operation...